# Fail to draw middle arrows with `decorations.markings` when `/pgfplots/trig format=rad`: Dimension too large

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,/pgfplots/trig format=rad} % remove and error is gone

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}]
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (-4,0) -- (-2,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This raises the error:

```
/home/ulysses/temp/test.tex:9: Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgfmath@x 
                           
l.9 ...w[postaction={decorate}] (-4,0) -- (-2,-1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the PGFPlots manual:

> At the time of this writing, this feature is in experimental state: it
> can happen that it breaks TikZ internals.

You can either use `trig format plots=rad` - only for plots. -or you can set the format back to `deg` when needed like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, trig format=rad}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}]
    \draw[postaction={decorate}, trig format=deg] (-4,0) -- (-2,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```